# Como fazer um preview de várias imagens diferentes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como faço pra fazer um preview de várias imagens diferentes a partir de inputs diferentes?

Aqui vai um exemplo de como eu queria que ficasse

**HTML**

```
<div class="col">
    <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" name="arquivo" id="files" onchange="preview(this);">
    <div class="preview-img">
        <img id="preview_image" alt="" src="">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col">
    <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" name="arquivo" id="files" onchange="preview(this);">
    <div class="preview-img">
        <img id="preview_image" alt="" src="">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col">
    <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" name="arquivo" id="files" onchange="preview(this);">
    <div class="preview-img">
        <img id="preview_image" alt="" src="">
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function preview(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#preview_image')
            .attr('src', e.target.result)
                                .width(100)
                                .height(100)
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rahnY/2/

Comment: Olá Altemberg. Editei a pergunta para incluir o código relevante aqui mesmo. É sempre importante fazer isso, para que as pessoas não precisam sair do site para entender o problema. Além disso, links externos podem ficar indisponíveis. Por favor leve isso em consideração nas próximas perguntas, e bom aprendizado!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Precisa de fazer esta alteração:

De:

```
$('#preview_image')
```

para

```
$(input).closest('.col').find('img.preview_image')
```

e remover os ID's duplicados aqui: `<img id="preview_image" alt="" src="">` mudando o ID para classe assim: `<img class="preview_image" alt="" src="">`.

**Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/X8LD5/**

A mudança de ID's duplicadas para classes tem mesmo de ser para não ter HTML inválido. O que estava a acontecer é que o código ia sempre buscar o primeiro elemento com a ID `preview_image`.

A mudança que fiz no jQuery é mais interessante e é relativa ao elemento `input` que foi mudado indo buscar o elemento pai mais proximo com a classe `col` e depois desce no DOM à procura da `img` com a classe `preview_image`, descendente desse elemento com class `col`.

Comment: Valeu, Sergio. Isso pode me servir até para problemas futuros.